# How to pass a function handler from controller into directive isolated scope in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function in controller:

```
  angular.module('app').controller('BodyController', function(){
    this.click = function(message){
      alert(message);
    }
  })
```

I want to pass this function into directive's isolated scope to call it with some specific params, something like that:

```
  angular.module('app').directive('custom', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        text: '@',
        click: '&click'
      },
      link: function(scope, element){
        //...
        scope.click('Hello, Plunker!');
        //...
      }
    }
  })
```

And I pass thefunction in this way:

```
<h1 custom text="Hello Plunker!" click="ctrl.click"></h1>
```

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4zkxuHJIB3D339h2Oy60?p=preview

The function is not called. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, opened your plunker, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like

```
 angular.module('app').directive('custom', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        text: '@',
        click: '=click'
      },
      link: function(scope, element){
      //  console.dir(scope.click);
      element.bind("click",function(){

         scope.click('Hello, Plunker!');
      });

        element.text('Hello, Plunker!');
      }
    }
  })
```

here you get click function from parent scope by click: '=click'

and bind that function to click on the element.

here is plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Ekw8I6Kg6tDOnIrnv4za?p=preview

or you can just pass the parameter into your directive like this http://plnkr.co/edit/mBbZil1jc4El2Jk79ru7?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

By using `click: '&click'` (which can be shortened to just `click: '&'`), you're saying "make `click` on the inner scope execute the expression in `'click'` attribute". That means that you need to actually call the method in the expression, not just point to it.

```
<h1 click="ctrl.click()">...</h1>
```

---

If, on the other hand you want to get a reference to the outer function and then play with it (e.g. pass arguments to it), you need to get it using:

```
scope: {
    click: '='
}
```

or just use solution by @michael-zuchetta, which was new to me :)

Comment: How can I pass a parameter to click function from the directive in this case?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include this (and deleted my ignorant comment about it being impossible).

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution:

```
<h1 custom text="Hello Plunker!" click="click(message)"></h1>
```

Add the message parameter and then bind it :

```
 scope.click({message: "Hello Plunker:"});
```

This is the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u748hLvn/2/